# Displaying data in one column on a Category wiki page

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

Is it possible to format a Category page on a wiki (I'm working on a MediaWiki but I suppose it's the same for all) so it shows all the categories in one column instead of the [default-3 columns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aPresidents_of_the_United_States)?

If not, is there a way to create another kind of page that dynamically updates its content as a Category page does? I couldn't find an example on wikipedia.

Comment: I really doubt it would be the same for all different wiki applications.

Comment: Also, are you willing to change the source code of your local MediaWiki installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both [Extension:Semantic Mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Semantic_Mediawiki) and [Extension:Dynamic Page List](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aDynamicPageList_%28third-party%29) are pretty potent tools that allow the creation of pages with dynamic lists and tables and so on.